# NodeJS Mongoose collection.remove not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to drop all docs in all collections before unit tests run...

```
var collections = mongoose.connection.collections;
async.eachSeries(_.keys(collections), function(key, cb){

  collections[key].remove(function(){
    //Never gets here, doesn't drop the collection and doesn't error.
    cb();
  });
}
```

But the callback in remove() never gets fired.
I've logged out `collections[key]` and it does resolve to a collection.

No errors, but it times out as it never runs the callback.

Ive tried looping the Models as well and calling that `remove` but its the same issue.

What am I doing wrong here??  Any logs I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the drop method:

```
var async = require("async"),
    _ = require("underscore"),
    collections = _.keys(mongoose.connection.collections);

async.forEach(collections, function(key, done) {
    var collection = mongoose.connection.collections[key]
    collection.drop(function(err) {
        if (err && err.message != "ns not found") {
            done(err);
        } else {
            done(null);
        }
    })
}, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try the following:

```
var collections = mongoose.connection.collections;
async.eachSeries(_.keys(collections), function(key, cb){
  mongoose.connection.db.collection(key, function(err, col) {
    col.remove({}, function(){
      cb();
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Tried that, same results

Comment: Added some logging into the Test DB connection, and looks like some one has re named the test DB in the env settings.  But mongo doesn't log any errors unless you wire up the error events.   Now have errors wired up for the test db.   But it did log all the Collections, which I don't get, maybe it somehow is using a connection to the main DB?  So confused - thanks for your help

Comment: Well, it logs all the collection because mongoose creates all of the collections when you register the models, which I'm assuming is on server start.

Comment: Yeah, thats what foxed me.  Sorry for wasting your time, appriciate the help. m

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated issue, it wasn't connecting to the DB in the test environment.  But no errors were reported, and it had a valid list of collections due to mongoose models.

I added the following to the test set up to log out the errors and other info to help find these issues in the future...

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + config.db.url);
});


mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected');
});
```